# Dialog flow fulfillment integration with Angular not providing proper replies

Tags: javascript, angular, dialogflow-es

Dialog flow chatbot integrated with Angular is not providing proper replies.

I have integrated Dialog flow with Angular. I'm using Firebase for the back end. Following the commands in this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?authuser=2

The chat bot works properly for first 3 intents but after that it is not providing the trained reply. I'm a beginner and I don't know where I'm going wrong.

This is the index.js file I have integrated to my Angular project

```
'use strict';

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {WebhookClient} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');
const {Card, Suggestion} = require('dialogflow-fulfillment');

process.env.DEBUG = 'dialogflow:debug'; // enables lib debugging statements

exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
  const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });
  console.log('Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers));
  console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

  function welcome(agent) {
    agent.add(`Welcome to my agent!`);
  }

  function fallback(agent) {
    agent.add(`I didn't understand`);
    agent.add(`I'm sorry, can you try again?`);
  }

  function checkHousingProblems(agent) {
    let HousingProblems = agent.parameters.HousingProblems;
    if (HousingProblems=='2'){
        agent.add('Do you live in residence or off campus?');
    }else if (HousingProblems=='3'){
        agent.add('Do you live in residence or off campus?');
    }else if (HousingProblems=='quite a bit'){
        agent.add('Do you live in residence or off campus?');
    }else if (HousingProblems=='extremely'){
        agent.add('Do you live in residence or off campus?');
    }else {
        agent.add('How much do the following issues contribute to your stress? • Legal issues  0 = not at all  1 = somewhat  2 = quite a bit  3 = extremely');
    }
  }

  function checkHousingStatus(agent) {
    let HousingStatus = agent.parameters.HousingStatus;
    if (HousingStatus=='residence'){
        agent.add('For concerns about residence contact residence services.');
    }else if (HousingStatus=='off campus'){
        agent.add('For concerns related to living off campus');
    }
    agent.add('How much do the following issues contribute to your stress? • Legal issues 0 = not at all  1 = somewhat  2 = quite a bit  3 = extremely');
  }

  let intentMap = new Map();
  intentMap.set('Default Welcome Intent', welcome);
  intentMap.set('Default Fallback Intent', fallback);
  intentMap.set('LifeProblemsQ2', checkHousingProblems);
  intentMap.set('LifeProblemsQ2PartB', checkHousingStatus);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', yourFunctionHandler);
  // intentMap.set('your intent name here', googleAssistantHandler);
  agent.handleRequest(intentMap);
});
```

This is my chat.service.ts code

```
export class ChatService {

  private token = environment.dialogflow.sciofreliefbot;
  private client = new ApiAiClient({accessToken: this.token});

  conversation = new BehaviorSubject<Message[]>([]);

  constructor() { }

  update(msg: Message) {
    this.conversation.next([msg]);
  }

  converse(msg: string) {
    const userMessage = new Message(msg, 'user');
    this.update(userMessage);

    return this.client.textRequest(msg)
    .then(res => {
      const speech = res.result.fulfillment.speech;
      const botMessage = new Message(speech, 'bot');
      this.update(botMessage);
    });
  }

  talk() {
    this.client.textRequest('Hi')
    .then(res => console.log(res));

  }
```

chat-dialog.component.ts code

```
export class ChatDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  messages: Observable<Message[]>;
  formValue: string;

  constructor(public chat: ChatService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.messages = this.chat.conversation.asObservable()
    .scan((acc, val) => acc.concat(val));
  }

  sendMessage() {
    this.chat.converse(this.formValue);
    this.formValue = '';
  }

}
```

chat-dialog.component.html code

```
<h1> Sci of Relief Chat bot</h1>

<ng-container *ngFor="let message of messages | async">
    <div class="message" [ngClass]="{'from': message.sentBy === 'bot',
                                        'to': message.sentBy === 'user'}">

        {{ message.content }}

    </div>
</ng-container>

<label for="nameField"> Your Message </label>

<input [(ngModel)] ="formValue" (keyup.enter)="sendMessage()" type="text"><br>

<button (click)="sendMessage()">Send</button>
```

When I'm using the webdemo link in dialog flow I'm getting the below output

User: 3

Bot: Do you live in residence or off campus?

User: residence

Bot: For concerns about residence contact residence services.

When I'm using in my Angular website I'm not getting an reply after 'residence'

Would be helpful if someone can point me where I'm going wrong.

Comment: Could you provide the history log for this interaction on the dialogflow console?
Review the following:
1. In the intent LifeProblemsQ2PartB is activated the fulfillment option?
2. This is the correct name of the intent LifeProblemsQ2PartB?

Comment: @Deyvid, The responses are coming as expected in the dialog flow console. Only when I integrate it with my Angular website it is not providing the response. I have reviewed your suggestions 1. Yes LifeProblemsQ2PartB is activated in the fulfillment option 2. Yes the name of the intent is correct. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Maybe the raw interaction log, from the History tab on Dialogflow Console will be useful. But I think your problem is the sessionID, this parameter let Dialogflow to establish the thread of the conversation. In your Angular app you are not sending that pararemeter, so every message is a independent conversation.

Comment: @Deyvid, Can you suggest any other method to integrate the Dialogflow with Angular?

Answer (score 0):

Without the Raw Interaction logs, it is very difficult. But Maybe your session ID is different every call to DialogFlow. Put the SessionId hardcode on the constructor of **ApiAiClient** on the **ChatService** Class.

```
export class ChatService {

  private token = environment.dialogflow.sciofreliefbot;
  private client = new ApiAiClient({accessToken: this.token, sessionId  : 'sessionId' });
...
}
```

If it works, check the lifeCycle of the **ChatService** class to be create only once on every Angular App. Or send a sessionId related to the client (like a cookie)

Comment: The error was due to a Dialog flow fullfilment function which was returning two responses as a single text and the function which I wrote to display them was not able to recognize them. I have resolved it by changing the fulfillment function to return proper messages. Thanks for your suggestions

Answer (score 0):

The error was due to a Dialog flow fullfilment function which was returning two responses as a single text and the function which I wrote to display them was not able to recognize them. I have resolved it by changing the fulfillment function to return proper messages.